# Is there a particular range for good perplexity value in NLP?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, language-model, perplexity

I'm fine-tuning a language model and am calculating training and validation losses along with the training and validation perplexities. It s calculated by taking the exponential of the loss, in my program. I'm aware that lower perplexities represent better language models and is wondering what the range of values are for a good model. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.